# C# DataVisualization.Charting.Chart not aggregating x axis

Tags: c#, datetime, charts, data-visualization, timeline

I'm using the Winform DataVisualization.Charting.Chart control. I have added 3 data series into the default chartarea. Each series has an integer y value and a Datetime x value.

If I show any one data series, it works as expected; however, if I combine the data series the dates overlap and are not in chronological order thus making the chart useless. I've hard-coded the values just for a sanity check but still see the same issue.

If anyone knows for a way for this chart to have a single x axis timeline that all data series will just plot the y value onto, it would be greatly appreciated. I've run out of things to try. (Image include below...)

```
        chrtSessions.ChartAreas.Clear();
        chrtSessions.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea("Default"));
        chrtSessions.Series.Clear();
        chrtSessions.Titles.Clear();
        chrtSessions.Titles.Add("Hours Left For Licensure");
        chrtSessions.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.Title = "Hours";
        chrtSessions.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX.Title = "Dates";
        chrtSessions.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
        chrtSessions.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "DD/MM/YYYY";

        chrtSessions.Series.Add("Individual");
        chrtSessions.Series["Individual"].AxisLabel = "Individual Sessions";
        chrtSessions.Series["Individual"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        chrtSessions.Series["Individual"].BorderWidth = 4;
        chrtSessions.Series["Individual"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;

        for (int index = 0; index < individualData.hours.Count; index++)
        {
            chrtSessions.Series["Individual"].Points.AddXY(individualData.dates[index].ToShortDateString(), individualData.hours[index]);
        }

        chrtSessions.Series.Add("Relational");
        chrtSessions.Series["Relational"].AxisLabel = "Relational Sessions";
        chrtSessions.Series["Relational"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        chrtSessions.Series["Relational"].BorderWidth = 4;
        chrtSessions.Series["Relational"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;

        for (int index = 0; index < relationalData.hours.Count; index++)
        {
            chrtSessions.Series["Relational"].Points.AddXY(relationalData.dates[index].ToShortDateString(), relationalData.hours[index]);
        }

        chrtSessions.Series.Add("Supervision");
        chrtSessions.Series["Supervision"].AxisLabel = "Supervision Sessions";
        chrtSessions.Series["Supervision"].ChartType= SeriesChartType.Line;
        chrtSessions.Series["Supervision"].BorderWidth = 4;
        chrtSessions.Series["Supervision"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;

        for (int index = 0; index < supervisionData.hours.Count; index++)
        {
            chrtSessions.Series["Supervision"].Points.AddXY(supervisionData.dates[index].ToShortDateString(), supervisionData.hours[index]);
        }
```

[Notice on this image that the Date 11/19/2021 occurs twice, but with 11/20/2021 occurring in-between and only yellow dataset actually has data that goes to the 23rd (data should show from 10/29-11/23). The blue line should span 10/31-11/20 and the red line should span from 10/26-11/19.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hM9B.png)

Comment: _Each series has an integer y value and a Datetime x value._ No! You add the x-values as strings, so strings they are. (`Points.AddXY(supervisionData.dates[index].ToShortDateString(),`) - A common mistake and the resulting x-values all are 0 (! check in the debugger!!) - You need to add them as datetime if the values are supposed to work.

Comment: @TaW Thank you so much. That was a clear oversight on my part and it obviously is the fix. I appreciate the response.